# Android Simulator Video Capture Tool

Tags: android, screen, capture, simulator

Is there any tool available that can capture video of simulator screen. Means what we do on simulator like launching different activities, selection of different actions, a video of those actions can be captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific tool - but you can just use a screen capture software like [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) (Open Source) and limit the recording are to the emulator screen.

Comment: +1 Works on Windows, the analogue of proprietary Camtasia Studio